# C# - How to access property of an array object?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I dont know how to show clearly, so:
Example - I create an array of button like this:

```
Button[,] _button = new Button[3, 3];

public MainPage()
{    
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
   _button[i, j] = new Button();
   _button[i, j].Name = "btn" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
   _button[i, j].Tag = 0;

   //Add Click event Handler for each created button
   _button[i, j].Click += _button_Click;

   boardGrid.Children.Add(_button[i, j]);
   Grid.SetRow(_button[i, j], i);
   Grid.SetColumn(_button[i, j], j);
  }
} // end MainPage()

private void _button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 Button b = (Button)sender;
 if (...)
   b.Tag = 1;
 else
   b.Tag = 2;
}// end Click Event
```

Now how can I compare the Tag of 2 buttons in that array like:

```
b[1,1].Tag == b[1,2].Tag ? ...<do st>... : ....<do st>...
```

Comment: Where is your problem?

Comment: I did ask my question:
how can I compare the Tag of 2 buttons in that array like:
    b[1,1].Tag == b[1,2].Tag ? ...<do st>... : ....<do st>...

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve and what was the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry for not clearly.
But I cannot access the Tag property like b[1,1].Tag
When I type b[1,1] - there is no property show up.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it should be _button[1,1].Tag == _button[1,2].Tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to find position of control in array consider to set [Control.Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to that position instead of search:

```
 _button[i, j].Tag = new System.Drawing.Point{ X = j, Y = i};
```

And instead of searching just

```
 Point position = (Point)((Button)sender).Tag;
```

Or if you need more information (like Position + 0/x/empty choice you have) - have custom class to hold all information you need:

```
 enum CellState { Empty, Player1, Player2 };
 class TicTacToeCell
 {
      public Point Position {get;set;}
      public CellState State {get;set;}
 }
```

Now when you have position and state - use `_buttons` array to index access other ones:

Check same row:

```
Point position = (Point)((Button)sender).Tag;
int player1CountInThisRow = 0;
for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++)
{
   if (((TicTacToeCell)(_button[position.Y, col].Tag).State == CellState.Player1)
   {
         player1CountInThisRow ++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I should try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a long-winded clarification than a definite answer, but it may uncover what you're *really* trying to do:

In the code that you show `b` is (presumably) a single `Button`, not an *array* of buttons.  Do you mean:

```
_button[1,1].Tag == _button[1,2].Tag ? ...<do st>... : ....<do st>...
```

Or are you trying to compare `b` (the event sender) to a button *relative to it* in the array?

Comment: yes - that's exactly what I mean!
Thank you for explaining that that clearly!
I'm trying to compare b (the event sender) to a button relative to it in the array.